# make public website reconnect to local html or xampp

Tags: html, redirect, xampp, localhost, hosts

Basically what I want to do is if I open this

> http://steamcommunity.com/market

website on my pc I want to see a local website that is stored as html. I already tried to host the website with xampp which worked and trying to add

> localhost/path http://steamcommunity.com/market

to my hosts file.

but instead of redirecting me to my local hosted html file it just loaded the steam market.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you'd wanna do this, but your hostsfile should be:

```
127.0.0.1  www.steamcommcunity.com
::1        www.steamcommcunity.com
127.0.0.1  steamcommunity.com
::1        steamcommunity.com
```

Just to be on the safe side I've used both with and without `www`, and both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: That won't work either. `hosts` only works on hostnames, not paths.

Comment: Ah, that's true. I completely forgot about that. Fixed my answer

Comment: 127.0.0.1 leads me to my xampp dashboard doesn't it?

Comment: Unless you set up your virtual host, probably

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process: first, you have to redirect the web site name to your computer; next, you get Apache to redirect the web site address to your installed directory.

**Locate your hosts file,**

Add lines containing the domain name(s) and IP address to redirect to.

Each line must begin with the address 127.0.0.1 (this is the localhost address)

After the IP address, type the name of the domain you wish to redirect to this address. You may only enter 1 name per line.

Addresses like my-site.com and www.my-site.com are different and each need a separate line.

Save the changes.

Next,

**Locate the httpd-vhosts.conf file. For most XAMPP 1.7.3 installs this will be C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra**

Add the new host,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.joomla.16
    ServerAlias joomla.16
    DocumentRoot d:/xampp/htdocs/path/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Explanation of VirtualHost preparation,

**ServerName:** following this label, add the name of the domain you added in

**ServerAlias:** following this label, you may add as many alternate domains (separated by spaces) as you like that are supposed to resolve to this virtual host. Remember that www.my-domain.com is different from my-domain.com, but, typically, you would want them to resolve to the same server.

**DocumentRoot:** following this label, add the path where your website is located. You can use an absolute path (as in the example above), or a relative path (but relative paths can be trickier to set up, so I prefer to use an absolute path).

**Restart Apache Web Server**

You should now be able to type the domain name into your URL field and go directly to your locally hosted web site:

Please see [this tutorial](https://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name) for more help.